# How to write a caption for a plot in iPython Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, caption

I am using iPython Notebook as my lab notebook. I wonder how to write a caption for each figure. For example, if I generate a figure using `plt.plot([1,2,3])`, I'd like to write a caption beside the figure to explain what that figure means - apart from setting xlabel, ylabel, title, etc.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [figure caption centering in nbconvert?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264205/figure-caption-centering-in-nbconvert)

Comment: Thanks, Gàbor. The page you shared is relevant. In this way, I can centre the caption. Do you know how I may centre my plot as well? As my plots appear left aligned in the notebook, if I just centre align the caption, they look unorganised. I was thinking of putting the caption on the right side of a plot. However, I may need to use a table for that. Is there any easier way to align a caption with a plot together? Cheers.